# What is Protagonist placing inside the case here?

Tags: tenet

I didn't understand, What is Protagonist placing inside the
case here?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As we can see in the [original screenplay](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1-T3zyGiaNczvSvASWD_T8WCcv3aMcGLG/view), It was his bluetooth headset.

> The Protagonist pulls onto a busy highway where the cars are
> FACING HIM, BUT MOVING IN HIS DIRECTION...
>
> The Saab races along, the only normal-looking car on a road
> full of cars SPEEDING BACKWARDS...
>
> On the phone, the flashing dot is CLOSER...
>
> Slowing, the Protagonist spots the ORANGE CASE lying empty by
> the side of the road. **He PULLS OVER some distance away –
> JUMPS out of the car – pulls out his BLUETOOTH EARPIECE and
> WEDGES it between the foam padding and the orange plastic...**
>
> The Protagonist heads back to his car, checks the signal from
> his phone... PEERS at the case...

Comment: It was foreshadowed only a few seconds earlier when he was handed both when he went through the airlock; "*Neil hands him a phone. The Protagonist sticks a Bluetooth
earpiece in his ear, passes into the airlock – Wheeler shuts
it behind him. Then opens the OUTER DOOR...*"

Answer (score 2):

It's a small wireless microphone. The Protagonist put it in there to [bug](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Covert_listening_device) the case. It's how the Protagonist heard the following communication Sator had with his henchman:

> Sator: The material's not in the case.
> Sator: Get the other sections of the algorithm to the hypocenter.
> Sator: He was lying. It wasn't in the BMW.
> Henchman: So, where is it?